# I added one extra RepConv in yoloV7 and encouter some issues

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, yaml, yolov7

I added an extra repConv and anchors as below, and my first epoch P, R, mAP 0.5 are all zeros, please help...

[first epoch image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKrEV.png)

```
# parameters
nc: 80  # number of classes
depth_multiple: 1.0  # model depth multiple
width_multiple: 1.0  # layer channel multiple

# anchors
anchors:
  - [8, 12, 14, 20, 22, 30]
  - [12,16, 19,36, 40,28]  # P3/8
  - [36,75, 76,55, 72,146]  # P4/16
  - [142,110, 192,243, 459,401]  # P5/32

# yolov7 backbone
backbone:
  # [from, number, module, args]
  [
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [32, 3, 1]],  # 0
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [64, 3, 2]],  # 1-P1/2
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [64, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 3, 2]],  # 3-P2/4

# ELAN 1
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [64, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, GhostConv, [64, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [64, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [64, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [64, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [64, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -3, -5, -6], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 1, 1]],  # 11
   [-1, 1, CBAM, [256, 1]],

# MP 1
   [-1, 1, MP, []],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-3, 1, GhostConv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 3, 2]],
   [[-1, -3], 1, Concat, [1]],  # 16-P3/8

# ELAN 2
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, GhostConv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -3, -5, -6], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [512, 1, 1]],  # 25
   [-1, 1, CBAM, [512, 1]],

# MP 2
   [-1, 1, MP, []],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-3, 1, GhostConv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 3, 2]],
   [[-1, -3], 1, Concat, [1]],  # 29-P4/16

# ELAN 3
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, GhostConv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -3, -5, -6], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [1024, 1, 1]],  # 39
   [-1, 1, CBAM, [1024, 1]],

# MP 3
   [-1, 1, MP, []],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [512, 1, 1]],
   [-3, 1, GhostConv, [512, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [512, 3, 2]],
   [[-1, -3], 1, Concat, [1]],  # 42-P5/32

# ELAN 4
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, GhostConv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -3, -5, -6], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [1024, 1, 1]],  # 53
   [-1, 1, CBAM, [1024, 1]]
  ]

# yolov7 head
head:
  [
   [-1, 1, SPPCSPC, [512]], # 55
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, nn.Upsample, [None, 2, 'nearest']],
   [39, 1, GhostConv, [256, 1, 1]], # route backbone P4
   [[-1, -2], 1, Concat, [1]],

# ELAN 5
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, GhostConv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 1, 1]], # 67
   
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, nn.Upsample, [None, 2, 'nearest']],
   [25, 1, GhostConv, [128, 1, 1]], # route backbone P3
   [[-1, -2], 1, Concat, [1]],

# ELAN 6
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, GhostConv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [64, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [64, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [64, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [64, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 1, 1]], # 79
      
   [-1, 1, MP, []],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-3, 1, GhostConv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 3, 2]],
   [[-1, -3, 67], 1, Concat, [1]],

# ELAN 7
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, GhostConv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 1, 1]], # 92
      
   [-1, 1, MP, []],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-3, 1, GhostConv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 3, 2]],
   [[-1, -3, 55], 1, Concat, [1]],

# ELAN 8
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [512, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, GhostConv, [512, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, GhostConv, [512, 1, 1]], # 105

#================================================
   [79, 1, GhostConv, [32, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, nn.Upsample, [None, 2, 'nearest']],
   [11, 1, GhostConv, [64, 1, 1]],
   [[-1, -2], 1, Concat, [1]], #109

# ELAN 9
   [ -1, 1, GhostConv, [ 64, 1, 1 ] ],
   [ -2, 1, GhostConv, [ 64, 1, 1 ] ],
   [ -1, 1, GhostConv, [ 32, 3, 1 ] ],
   [ -1, 1, GhostConv, [ 32, 3, 1 ] ],
   [ -1, 1, GhostConv, [ 32, 3, 1 ] ],
   [ -1, 1, GhostConv, [ 32, 3, 1 ] ],
   [ [ -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6 ], 1, Concat, [ 1 ] ],
   [ -1, 1, GhostConv, [ 64, 1, 1 ] ], # 117

   [ -1, 1, MP, [ ] ],
   [ -1, 1, GhostConv, [ 64, 1, 1 ] ],
   [ -3, 1, GhostConv, [ 64, 1, 1 ] ],
   [ -1, 1, GhostConv, [ 64, 3, 2 ] ],
   [[-1, -3], 1, Concat, [1]],  # 122

# ELAN 10
   [ -1, 1, GhostConv, [ 128, 1, 1 ] ],
   [ -2, 1, GhostConv, [ 128, 1, 1 ] ],
   [ -1, 1, GhostConv, [ 64, 3, 1 ] ],
   [ -1, 1, GhostConv, [ 64, 3, 1 ] ],
   [ -1, 1, GhostConv, [ 64, 3, 1 ] ],
   [ -1, 1, GhostConv, [ 64, 3, 1 ] ],
   [ [ -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6 ], 1, Concat, [ 1 ] ],
   [ -1, 1, GhostConv, [ 64, 1, 1 ] ], # 130

#================================================
   [130, 1, RepConv, [128, 3, 1]],  # 131
#================================================
   [79, 1, RepConv, [256, 3, 1]],  # 132
   [92, 1, RepConv, [512, 3, 1]],  # 133
   [105, 1, RepConv, [1024, 3, 1]], # 134

   [[131,132,133,134], 1, IDetect, [nc, anchors]],   # Detect(P3, P4, P5)
  ]
```

I tried changing the backbone and neck of yolov7 , the biggest change is adding additonal repconv to the head and addtional anchors and my map.5 is zero, pleae help

the first time i added addtional RepConv without adding the andchors i encounter this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/media/user/Storage/alex/yolov7_ghostconv/train.py", line 616, in 
train(hyp, opt, device, tb_writer)
File "/media/user/Storage/alex/yolov7_ghostconv/train.py", line 88, in train
model = Model(opt.cfg or ckpt['model'].yaml, ch=3, nc=nc, anchors=hyp.get('anchors')).to(device)  # create
File "/media/user/Storage/alex/yolov7_ghostconv/models/yolo.py", line 548, in **init**
m.anchors /= m.stride.view(-1, 1, 1)
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (3) must match the size of tensor b (4) at non-singleton dimension 0

then i added this anchor(- [8, 12, 14, 20, 22, 30]) and I could run the train.py but my map.5 is zero.